# DropDownList from database in YII

Tags: php, yii

i am creating yii application first time, i have used following code to create dropdownlist in my view

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'CodeLookupId',Forms::model()->findAll());
```

it show me error

include(Forms.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

C:\wamp\www\LearningYii\protected\views\codelookup_form.php(35):

```
     <?php echo $form->textField($model,'ShortDesc',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50)); ?>
     <?php echo $form->error($model,'ShortDesc'); ?>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
     <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'CodeLookupId',Forms::model()->findAll()); ?>
 </div>

 <div class="row buttons">
     <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$opts = CHtml::listData(Codelookup::model()->findAll(),'CodeLookupId','CodeDesc');
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'ParentCodeLookupId',$opts,array('empty'=>''));
```

This code is working

Answer (score 1):

use CHtml::listData to convert the db object to list data:

Here ID , NAME is your table values which should be used in option value and option text.

```
 <?php 
    $opts = CHtml::listData(Forms::model()->findAll(),'CodeLookupId','CodeLookupId');
    //to check list
    print_r($opts);
    echo $form->dropDownList($model,'CodeLookupId',$opts); 
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @kumar_v,but syntax is incorrect ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\wamp\www\LearningYii\protected\views\codelookup\_form.php on line 35

Comment: <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'codelookup',CHtml::listData(Forms::model()->findAll(),'CodeLookupId','CodeLookupId')); ?>... not working , codelookup is my modelname

Answer (score 0):

```
try hope this will help..
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
<?php
$records = loaddataform::model()->findAll();
$list = CHtml::listData($records, 'id', 'username');
echo CHtml::dropDownList('loaddataform', $model, 
      CHtml::listData($records,
      'a_id', 'a_name'),
      array('empty' => '(Select a name)'));
 ?>
 </div>


and in controller

public function actionloaddata()
{

$model = new loaddataform;
$models = loaddataform::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'a_name'));
$list = CHtml::listData($models, 'a_id', 'a_name');
$this->render('loaddata',array('model'=>$model));

}
This works correctly..it retrives name from database.
```